# Behringer Xenyx 1002 output to Samsung DVD player AUX

Tags: mixer, dvd, macbook-pro, recorder-mixer

I'm looking at purchasing the [Behringer Xenyx 1002](http://musicmate.co.za/product/behringer-xenyx-1002-10-input-mixer-with-2-x-preamps-eq/) audio mixer for an amateur home studio setup in a small 4m x 4m room at home.

[image]

I would like to connect a MacBook pro via USB to the mixer, an Ovation Celebrity guitar, as well as an Alesis DM6 drumkit, and later an electric piano and perhaps a microphone or two.

I don't have a super expensive speaker setup and being a small room it doesn't need much. I want to repurpose 4x 30Watt 3Ω speakers and a subwoofer from a Samsung 5.1 surround sound DVD player system I have laying around.

Can I feed the output from the mixer into AUX into my Samsung DVD player to get the sound playing through it?

Alternatively, can I solder some audio jacks onto the speakers and plug them directly into the mixer?

Last question, can the mixer both play and record audio through the USB interface at the same time on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, I'd say that the mixer qx1002 model which I also own

You can connect the macbook via usb and send the signal to mains by pressing th button labled USB/2tr to Main Mix, alternativly the signal can be send to phones only

Note that the mixer only has two preamps - so if you're pluging in acoustic guitars or microphones without external preamps make sure you use the first two inputs - so for acoustic guitar and 2 mics you need an external preamp for one of those

Sending phones output from the mixer to the aux input in the dvd is preffered as it's stereo to stereo jack, and will probably require only an 1/4 jack adapter and cable

Directly soldering cables from mixer to speakers has no effect as you still need an power amplifier in between - evan with an amp this can also add hum and unwanted noises

Sadly, the audio interface on the mixer permits only one operation at a time - play or record

Comment: That's a great answer Dalv, thanks for that. Is there a way to take audio output from the recording MacBook and inserting that signal into the cd/tape inputs on the top right of the mixer?

Comment: And another question, can the mac/macbook playing audio do so through for example iTunes, or do I have to use the mixer's software. To put that differently, does Mac OS X see the device as USB audio output in System Preferences > Sound?

Comment: Using both the Behringer usb interface and the soundboard from the macbook simultaneously is not possible so there will be no signal to send through the cd/tape. Also the 2tr input is the same as the usb so either one or the other is used.

The mixer is recognized as an usb audio interface